# Exclude null properties when converting object to string via toString()

Tags: java, tostring

```
class Person {
  public String name;
  public String nickname;
}
```

When converting a POJO from Object to String, I want to exclude any values which are null, so that if I have `Person = {name = "Jack", nickname = null}`, the toString() will just return `{name = "Jack"}`

Is this use case possible?

Edit: Yes, I am using Lombok. Maybe the solution is to implement my own toString()

#### References:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/project-lombok/YC-eo2_XmsI

Answer (score 4):

As for now, [this feature](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1752) of omiting nulls is NYI in lombok, so you will have to implement your own toString method.

You can either use `StringJoiner` <sup>[1](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringJoiner.html)</sup> and skip nulls explicitly, or you can use a helper `ToStringHelper` <sup>[2](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#toStringHelper-java.lang.Class-)</sup> from Guava

```
class Person {
    public String name;
    public String nickname;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final var joiner = new StringJoiner(", ", Person.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]");
        if (name != null) {
            joiner.add("name='" + name + "'");
        }
        if (nickname != null) {
            joiner.add("nickname='" + nickname + "'");
        }
        return joiner.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .omitNullValues()
                .add("name", name)
                .add("nickname", nickname)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [commons-lang3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) to achieve your aim.

The only one thing what you need to do is to override the `toString()` method in the `Person` class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String nickName;

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final Object myself = this;
        ReflectionToStringBuilder builder = new ReflectionToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.JSON_STYLE) {
            @Override
            protected boolean accept(Field field) {
                try {
                    return super.accept(field) && field.get(myself) != null;
                }
                catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    return super.accept(field);
                }
            }
        };

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

The result if the `name` field value is not null but `nickName` is null:

```
{"name":"John"}
```

You need to add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.10</version>
</dependency>
```

The benefit of the usage of the `ReflectionToStringBuilder` class is that you do not need to touch your `toString()` method if you add a new class member variable because this class uses reflection.